# Android - get filepath of a file for EXIF

Tags: java, android

I'm currently developing an app that would take the photos from a specific folder in the gallery, get its metadata (Longitude and Latitude) and display them on a Map using these codes:

```
try {
     for(int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
     double Latitude =0;
     double Longitude = 0;
     ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(listFile[i].get);

            exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE);
            exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF);
            exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE);
            exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF);
            String LATITUDE = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE);
            String LATITUDE_REF = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF);
            String LONGITUDE = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE);
            String LONGITUDE_REF = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF);

            // your Final lat Long Values


            if ((LATITUDE != null)
                && (LATITUDE_REF != null)
                && (LONGITUDE != null)
                && (LONGITUDE_REF != null)) {

            if (LATITUDE_REF.equals("N")) {
                Latitude = convertToDegree(LATITUDE);
            } else {
                Latitude = 0 - convertToDegree(LATITUDE);
            }

            if (LONGITUDE_REF.equals("E")) {
                Longitude = convertToDegree(LONGITUDE);
            } else {
                Longitude = 0 - convertToDegree(LONGITUDE);
            }

        }
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Latitude, Longitude)).title("Picture")
                                          .snippet("lol" + i));
        /*mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(14.566, 120.993))
                        .title("Goks")
                        .snippet("Gokongwei")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                        .draggable(true)
        );*/


    }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However, the EXIF doesn't return anything. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure those attributes are present in the images' Exif data?

Comment: Yes! @MikeM I also included permissions in taking photos (those photos that were used to get the EXIF metadata)

Comment: First figure out if the Exif code is accessing the file at all, and if not solve that.  If it is, try looking for other data, specifically something known to exist (phone model, date, etc are probably in there).  You may want to copy a few representative files off the device and examine them with an exif tool.

Comment: Well, I really think the problem is I cannot retrieve the EXIF metadata given the PATH.

Comment: Are you sure your file paths are correct? They need to be the absolute paths. If those are good, then make sure you've got at least the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

Comment: What is PATH exactly? Example please. And what is 'the EXIF doesn't return anything'? Which statement exactly? Is null returned? Be exact!

Comment: Why are you talking about PATH if you use 'listFile[i].get'. Give an example of it's value please. listFile.get(i)?